# Is it the best or simplest way to use a lua variable in LaTeX code?

Tags: luatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}

for i = 1,10
do
    a = math.random(0,10) ;
    tex.print("--")
    tex.print("$\\sqrt{"..a.."}$") % <- simplest?
end
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\directlua`? This command is compatible with `TeX` parameters, macros, etc.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean? I don't see what alternatives you are expecting!

Comment: @JosephWright I think he want's an easier version of `"..a.."`.

Comment: I found this solution by my self. I don't if there is an alternative to my code, and indeed I'd expected something easier than ..a.. but if there isn't. I use LuaLaTeX, does it mean no \directlua ?

Comment: @1010011010 How to use `\directlua` in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

Note the code as posted generates an error as `luacode` reads its content verbatim so

```
 % <- simpliest ?
```

is passed to Lua and generates a syntax error.

But I don't think you need `luacode` here. You could just make the call to `math.random` directly inside the expansion of `\sqrt`.

Then I'd normally use a TeX loop around the outside, but here I've used another `\directlua` to access a Lua loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\def\x{--$\sqrt{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.random(0,10))}}$}

\directlua{for i=1,10 do tex.print("\string\\x") end}

\end{document}
```